# Power BI DAX - evaluate the correct costvalue

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new in Power BI and I need a little help. I have a table A with sales like this:

```
ITEMID | Invoicedate | Price 
5001   | 30.12.2019  | 500,00 
5001   | 20.01.2020  | 500,00
```

and another table B with different `Costvalue`:

```
ITEMID | Costvalue | Activationdate 
5001   |    250,00 | 17.08.2019 
5001   |    254,00 | 11.01.2020
```

To calculate the margin, the correct `Costvalue` must be used.

For the examples shown above:

- The correct margin for item 5001 with `Invoicedate` *30.12.2019* is 250,00 (= 500,00 - 250,00).
- The correct margin for item 5001 with `Invoicedate` 20.01.2020 is 246,00 (= 500,00 - 254,00), as the new higher `Costvalue` is active since 20.01.2020.

How can I generate the correct `Costvalue` in relation to the `Activationdate` in DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create an end date field in table B. Something like the below:

```
End Date = 
    VAR ItemID='TableB'[Item ID]
    VAR Date1 = 'TableB'[Activation Date]
    VAR Enddate1=CALCULATE(MIN('TableB'[Activation Date]),FILTER('TableB','TableB'[Item ID]=ItemID),FILTER('TableB','TableB'[Activation Date]>Date1))
RETURN IF(Enddate1=BLANK(),DATE(2100,1,1),Enddate1)
```

Here, for the last record the end date is set to 2100 to avoid any confusion. Then you can create another calculated column to grab the COST value:

```
Cost = 
    VAR ItemID=TableA[ItemID]
    VAR Date1=TableA[Invoice Date]
    VAR Cost=CALCULATE(MIN(TableB[Cost Value]),FILTER(TableB,TableB[Item ID]=ItemID),FILTER(TableB,Date1>=TableB[Activation Date]),FILTER(TableB,Date1<=TableB[End Date]))
RETURN Cost
```

This should get you the cost value for each record. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following column to the sales table:

```
CostPrice = 
var tempTable = CALCULATE(MAX(Cost[ Activationdate ]); FILTER(Cost;Cost[ITEMID ] = Sales[ITEMID ] && Cost[ Activationdate ] < Sales[ Invoicedate ]))
return LOOKUPVALUE(Cost[ Costvalue ];Cost[ Activationdate ];tempTable)
```

it will create a temp table with the last activationdate for a product. With the lookup you pick the correct costvalue. Result:

[image]